# Implementing DAO using both Redis and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, redis

I'm developing a web application that uses both a MySQL server and a Redis server.
I followed the DAO design pattern and I'm having trouble deciding on the implementation of the interface.
Here are the questions at hand:

1. Should the interface include all of the functionality for both the MySQL and Redis?
2. Should I implement the interface for both the MySQL and redis separately? or should it be one implementation for both?
3. If the implementation is joined, how do I choose the dataSource each time?

I'm using the Spring Framework the connect to the data sources and run the various queries.
So far, I've only implemented the MySQL part using the Spring JDBCTemplate and with Tomcat connection pool. I'd be happy to get some advice on how to integrate the Redis bit with the Spring Framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an interface and two implementations: one for MySQL and another for Redis only. Then, in your service layer, inject the proper implementation of the DAO interface.

If you have a requirement where the data should be searched on Redis first, if it doesn't exist then look in MySQL, then you should implement this in your service layer, not in your DAO. Remember that DAO should only contain the necessary logic to communicate with the datasource.

Comment: Is it ok to leave some methods "empty"? I need some of them for Redis and some of them for MySQL.

Comment: That's not ok. Define a common interface, then sub interfaces and the implementation of each for your specific database. Note that your database engine could change from MySQL to another rdbms, similar with Redis.

Answer (score 0):

DAO is idepended of the tecnology as you probably know.

The interface interface should include the functionality to work wiht your bussiness objects so, your interface must include the full functionality.

One of the problems with the DAO in a traditional implementation is that you must pass as an argument the connection between DAOs to ensure the transaction. This is not happening with the IoC done at Spring Framework.

Spring decides the implemeantion for the DAO so you must configured at the injection engine. For the pool it depends of the redis client you are using.